# How do I make an implication from a venn diagram?

Tags: calculus, logic, propositional-calculus

I have the following venn diagram with the yellow that show with regions are True

[image]

My task is to:

Write a propositional statement using $\to$ and $\neg$ (if necessary) equivalent to regions 3, 5 and 6.

How exactly do I do this?

---

$$ 3 - [P \land Q \land \neg R] $$
$$ 5 - [P \land \neg Q \land R] $$
$$ 6 - [P \land Q \land  R] $$

---

How do I proceed from here? By the way, the answer is:
$$ (P \to \neg Q) \to \neg (P \to \neg R) $$

Comment: Can you describe what $\to$ means using and, or and not?

Comment: its just implication. im sorry i dont get what ur asking?

Comment: Have you learned how to describe $\to$ in terms of the and, or and not operators you used above.  There is a logical equivalence between $P \to Q$ and $\neg P \lor Q$

Comment: yes morgans laws

Comment: Do you need help manipulating $3 \lor 5 \lor 6$ in a simpler form?  You're definitions of 3,5,6 are correct.

Comment: is it $or$ , or is it $and$ ?

Comment: Or.  And would mean something would have to be in all three of them at once.  I'm writing up an explaination for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49873/discussion-between-lordoftheshadows-and-krac-x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct definitions for 3, 5, 6 however since you want all three of them you can describe it more easily as $(P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)$.

However since we want to write it only using $\to$ and $\neg$ we need to get it in a nicer form.  First let's remember that $A \to B = (\neg A \lor B)$.  However since we want to go the other way we need to remember that $\neg \neg A = A$.  So $(A \lor B) = (\neg A \to B)$.

Going back to our original statement we need to switch the $\land$s to $\lor$s.  So we use the rule $A\land B=\neg(\neg A \lor \neg B)$.

So rewriting the original we get $\neg(\neg P \lor \neg Q) \lor \neg(\neg P \lor \neg R)$.

Now substituting the identity we had earlier for the $\lor$ statements we get $\neg (P \to \neg Q) \lor \neg (P \to \neg Q)$.

And substituting one last time to get rid of the final $\lor$ we get $ (P \to \neg Q) \to \neg (P \to \neg R)$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you i understand the process, but just one question, when u said you can describe it more easily as P ^ Q or P ^ R .... how do u know that?

Comment: Remember that $A$ and $B$ don't have to be disjoint.  So we can see that $5 \lor 6 = P \land R$ and that $3 \lor 6 = P \land Q$.  The union of the two overlaps at $6$ but that's not a problem.

Comment: But if you do (P∧Q)∨(P∧R), both of these include region 6. Is it not a problem that we are comparing region 6 twice?

Comment: We are not using multisets so counting it twice does not matter.  More specifically the union of two sets ($P \land Q$ and $P \land R$) is the collection of objects such that the objects are in at least one of $P \land Q$ or $P \land R$.  It's ok if they are in both since they are also in one of them.  So it doesn't matter if the two sets overlap.

Comment: okay, thank you very much! :)

Comment: No problem.  I you wouldn't mind marking my answer as correct that would be appreciated.

Comment: ofcouse, glad to